# SecItemCopyMatching and kSecAttrAccessible in Keychain

Tags: ios, keychain

So my question is regarding how keychain access work. If I have already saved an item to keychain with `kSecAttrAccessible` attribute set, and If I want to query this item later on, do I have to include `kSecAttrAccessible` in my query dictionary for `SecItemCopyMatching` ? Does it make any difference other than narrowing down the search ?

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to include the `kSecAttrAccessible` attribute when querying unless, as you say, you want to narrow the search.

You should be able to empirically prove this to yourself by excluding the attribute when querying.

Comment: Yeah I thought the same. Just wanted to confirm. Thanks